# Amazon Redshift get list of identity columns for a table

Tags: amazon-redshift

How can I get a list of identity columns for a table in Amazon Redshift? (using system's tables)

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For those who might be interested to know about how to get all identity columns in a Redshift DB. The following query was posted by Neil@AWS to AWS Redshift Forum:

```
select 
    c.relname, 
    a.attname 
from pg_class c, pg_attribute a, pg_attrdef d 
where c.oid = a.attrelid 
    and c.relkind = 'r' 
    and a.attrelid = d.adrelid 
    and a.attnum = d.adnum 
    and d.adsrc like '%identity%' 
order by 1;
```

Comment: Just some additional information: the column `adsrc` in `pg_attrdef`contains information about identity in the form `"identity(table_id) (column_index) (text_representation of identity)`. So for a table (id=13123) which has the second column as `identity(1,1)` it would be  `"identity()"(13123), 1, '1,1'::text`.

Answer (score 0):

The [`PG_TABLE_DEF`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_PG_TABLE_DEF.html) table contains information about tables and columns:

```
select * from pg_table_def where tablename = 't2';
schemaname|tablename|column|  type   | encoding | distkey |sortkey| notnull 
----------+---------+------+---------+----------+---------+-------+---------
public    | t2      | c1   | bigint  | none     | t       |     0 | f
public    | t2      | c2   | integer | mostly16 | f       |     0 | f
public    | t2      | c3   | integer | none     | f       |     1 | t
public    | t2      | c4   | integer | none     | f       |     2 | f
(4 rows)
```

Also, the standard PostgreSQL catalog tables are accessible to Amazon Redshift users. For more information about PostgreSQL system catalogs, see [PostgreSQL System Tables](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/catalogs.html#CATALOGS-OVERVIEW).

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this table does not give you any information about "Identity" columns. There must be a system table which contains this information but still I could not find it.

Comment: What do you mean by "Identity" columns? Primary keys?

Comment: They are auto increment columns in RedShift.